# Java. Дженерики и приведение типов

Tags: java, generics

Здравствуйте! Имеется следующий обобщенный метод:

```
public static <T> List<T> getAllRecords(String table, String columnLabel) throws SQLException {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table);

    while(rs.next())
        list.add((T)rs.getString(columnLabel));

    return list;
}
```

Вот на этой строчке

```
list.add((T)rs.getString(columnLabel));
```

компилятор ругается

> Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
>
> ```
> void f(HashMap map) {
>     map.put("key", "value");
> }
> ```
>
> Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

То есть он (компилятор) имеет ввиду, что имеется непроверенное преобразование. Вы можете подсказать, что именно происходит в упоминаемой строчке и как будет правильней написать код? Как я понял происходит преобразование к типу, которого не существует, поэтому он и ругается...

Comment: Компилятор выражает сомнение, что тип `String` можно привести к типу `T`. Если бы `T` был нормальным типом, можно было бы успокоить компилятор, добавив проверку с помощью `instanceof`. В вашем случае надо просто убрать объявление `T` и возвращать `List<String>`, т.к. `resultSet.getString` возвращает строки и так. Или вы хотите написать метод, который возвращает столбец из таблицы нужного типа?

Comment: Просто стало интересно) В принципе да, и так String возвращается. А есть идея, как удобно возвращать столбец из таблицы нужного типа?

Comment: Если в Java 8, то можно передавать в метод лямбду или method reference, которые будут доставать из result set значение с нужным типом (http://pastebin.com/JsRhNsDX), вроде должно сработать, но я не проверял.

Comment: У компилятора нет возможности проверить какой тип лежит в `T` при компиляции, а у виртуальной машины нет возможности это проверить во время исполнения. Поэтому внутри параметризованного класса нельзя создавать объекты типа `T`, проверять, является ли тип объекта - `T` и выполнять подобные операции. Приводить объекты к типу `T` возможно(ошибки компиляции не случится) - но это бессмысленно. На самом деле компилятор не сможет проверить совместимость типа `T` и типа переданного объекта. Об этом и предупреждает вас компилятор